# Flask + WTForms: One function submit button for n-number of iterated forms

Tags: python, web, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm trying to integrate a grading program in my website and am struggling with getting the inputs (I'm a Flask newbie).

**What happens so far:**

- I ask the user for the number of students participating in (and the key of) the test (student_number) in the form TestSpecForm
- A page loads that iterates over this student_number and gives me an n=student_number amount of StringFields in which I can input the students' test performances (this form is the TestInputForm)
- There is ONE submit button

**The problem:**

- The submit button does not work (currently does nothing when I click on it)

Here are the details:

The **forms** look like this:

```
class TestSpecForm(FlaskForm):
    key = StringField('Key', validators=[DataRequired(), NoneOf(' ')])      
    student_number = IntegerField('Number of Students', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


class TestInputForm(FlaskForm):
    students = StringField('Student', validators=[DataRequired(), NoneOf(' ')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

The **models** look like this:

```
class Testspecs(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    key = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)  
    student_number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):     
        return f"Testspecs('{self.key}', '{self.student_number}', '{self.date_posted}')"


class S_Answers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    s_answer = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    key_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('testspecs.id'), nullable=False)
    key = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('testspecs.key'), nullable=False)
```

my **views/routes** look like this:

```
@app.route("/resources/testevaluation/<int:key_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def inpt(key_id):
    form = TestInputForm()
    key = Testspecs.query.get_or_404(key_id)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        s_answers = S_Answers(s_answer=form.students.data, key_id=key.id) 
        db.session.add(s_answers)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your student answers have been posted and will be evaluated shortly.')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('input.html', form=form, key=key, legend="Student Answers")
```

and finally the **template** 'input.html' looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ legend }}</legend>
    {% for number in range(key.student_number) %}
<div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {% if form.students.errors %}
                        {{ form.students(class="form-control form control-lg is-invalid") }}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.students.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        Student {{ number + 1 }}
                        {{ form.students(class="form-control form control-lg") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
    {% if form.submit %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Oh and [this is how the website looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCwTZ.png)

I've searched far and wide for similar problems and found some, but I still couldn't figure out what to do. I tried doing it with FieldList(Formfields) as well, but I couldn't figure out how to get n=student_number amount of Fields + the submit button didn't work there either.

Is there any way to have one functional submit button over an n number of iterated fields like this? I would greatly appreciate any and all help!

**/edit 1:**  If I put the {% endfor %} tag and the Submit button right before the  tag, I can press the Submit button but it gives me this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: S__answers.key [SQL: 'INSERT INTO "S__answers" (s_answer, key_id, "key") VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('e', 14, None)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

**/edit 2**: Have now updated my views/routes.py file to say "s_answers = S_Answers(s_answer=form.students.data, key_id=key.id, key=key.key)" which caused the error to disappear.

Now, however, there is another problem:

I tested whether the data is stored properly in the db by inputing "one", "two", and "three" as Student answers. In PowerShell I then queried the database for S_Answers.query.all() and it only yielded this:

```
[S_Answers('ABCDE', 'one')]  # "ABCDE" being the key
```

This means that only the very first instance of the loop seems to be stored. How can I make it so that all the forms in the loop are stored?

Comment: Try putting the sumit button inside the `<form></form>` tags.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
If I put the {% endfor %} tag and the Submit button right before the </form> tag, I can press the Submit button but it gives me this error:  "TypeError: 's_answers' is an invalid keyword argument for S_Answers", which, I assume, is some sort of error caused by the iteration.

Comment: In your model definition the field is `s_answer`, not `s_answers`.

Comment: Oh there's another problem now: It only saves the very first instance of the loop to the database. The others do not seem to be stored, at least not according to my S_Answers.query.all() query in the database. It only yielded the very first answer.